# problems with document.addEventListener() inside a chrome.request.sendRequest()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i have a google chrome extension in which I've created a background page that I query for my extension's settings, in my case I'm simply querying for a enabled/disabled variable.

first, here is the manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png",
        "48": "48.png",
        "16": "16.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["foo.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "background_page" : "background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/19x19.png",
        "default_title": "Foo",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

the background page's javascript looks like this:

```
FooApp = {};
FooApp.enabled = 1;

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.getSetting == "enabled") {
            sendResponse({result: FooApp.enabled});
        }
    }
);
```

and in my content script, I query the background page to see if the script is enabled & should execute:

```
(function() {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({getSetting: "enabled"}, function(response) {
        console.log("in sendRequest callback");
        if (response.result == 1) {
            console.log("in response.result = 1");
            document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
                console.log("in beforeload callback");
            }, true);
        } else {
            console.log("in response.result = 0");
        };
    });
}());
```

When I run this, I can see the console log for

1. "in sendRequest callback"
2. "in response.result = 1"

but I don't get the console log for "in beforeload callback" which is inside the callback for the "beforeload" event listener.

Is there something that I am missing....i expect the beforeload callback to fire and see the console log message but i don't. I am trying to query my app to check if it is enabled before I process any code inside my beforeload eventlistener.

the code runs fine when I remove everything other than the beforeload event listener registration, eg.:

```
document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
    console.log("in beforeload callback");
}, true);
```

it appears that the event listener never gets registered when it's nested within a `chrome.extension.sendRequest`? If I can't use this route to query my app settings, is there  a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You attach the event listener after the load event fires.

```
(function() {
// load event has already fired.
...
}());
```

Instead you should just execute the code inside the `if` that you were going to place inside the event listener.